# Wpf round weird border

Tags: wpf, border

[image]

Hi

I'm trying for over 2 days now to create toggle button that in pressed state like the above image, but that upper border is giving me a headache. Does anyone have any idea how to create that round corner that goes down? The background is a linear gradient top to bottom: #b8c7d6 - #a8b3c4

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!!

I have something like this but it is far from the design:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF4E4F50" CornerRadius="3"/>
                    <Border Background="Black" Margin="1" CornerRadius="3"/>
                    <Border Margin="2" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#0099B9D1" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF99B9D1" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#B299B9D1" Offset="0.054"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Margin="2" CornerRadius="3" Opacity="0.3">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                        <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00090909" Offset="0.022"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.99"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#45060606" Offset="0.001"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background></Border>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>


                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked well for me.  I found that the rounded corners added some additional challenges with creating the top area shadow correctly, but I was able to get that working by combining several techniques.

The **first technique** involves the clever use of two Borders.  The outer border has its **`ClipToBounds`** set to true, and the inner Border has a **`DropShadowEffect`**, with `ShadowDepth` set to 0 and a `BlurRadius` of around 5.  This gets us part of what we need, but it won't handle the rounded corner issue (we'll get to that).  This technique can be found at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225076/Creating-Inner-Shadows-for-WPF-and-Silverlight).  Here's the gist of it:

```
<Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-1">
    <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="6">
    </Border.Effect>
  </Border>
</Border>
```

If I recall correctly, at this point we would have something close to what you want, except that the `DropShadowEffect` "bleeds" out of the rounded corners (again we'll address that soon).

Another problem we would now have is that any child elements that we place inside the inner `Border` would also have the `DropShadowEffect` applied to them!  To correct that problem, we need the **second technique**.  Place the two `Borders`, along with another container (to hold your content) into a `Grid`, so that the outer `Border` and the new container are siblings.  This will cause the siblings to overlap each other, while only applying the `DropShadowEffect` to the `Border`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808165/718325).

Now to address the "bleed" issue, where the `DropShadowEffect` does not follow the contour of the rounded corners, but rather acts as if the corners were straight.  This requires the **third technique**.  We need to use [Michah's ClippingBorder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325003/718325) custom control.  We need to replace the above-mentioned outer `Border` control with his `ClippingBorder`, still keeping `ClipToBounds` set to true.  This will trim off the bleed at the rounded corners.

I was able to **combine these three techniques** to create a "sunk in" (or "inset") border look.  It looked something like:

```
<Grid>      
    <local:ClippingBorder x:Name="TopShadowClippingBorder" 
        BorderThickness="0" 
        CornerRadius="5" 
        ClipToBounds="True">

        <Border x:Name="TopShadowBorder" 
                BorderBrush="#D8333333" BorderThickness=".5,1,.5,0" 
                Padding="0" 
                CornerRadius="5" 
                ClipToBounds="True">        
                <Border.Effect>
                       <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="0.5"/>
                </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
    </local:ClippingBorder>

    <Border x:Name="InsetBorder" 
            BorderBrush="#99A1A1A1" BorderThickness="0.5,0,0.5,1" 
            CornerRadius="5" />

    <StackPanel x:Name="Contents_StackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        (Contents go here...)
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: Sunk-in border results]

Notice that the upper "glow" (DropShadowEffect) nicely follows the contour of the rounded corner of the Border:

[image: Sunk-in border glow follow contour of the rounded corner]

Answer (score 0):

I would use two borders: the outer would look something like:

```
<Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
```

The inner would create the shadow effect as follows:

```
<Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="2,4,2,0">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="#00000000"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
```

Obviously you'll need to tweak the values, but that should at least produce the effect you're after.

Comment: I have tried that but the end rounded corners don't look alike.. they are kinda straight. Thanks for your reply