# Shadow under hovered ListBoxItem (and not under it's text)

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate, listboxitem

I need shadow under `ListBoxItem` on `MouseOver`. Bottom code works but the whole listbox including the `TextBlock`'s letters have a shadow:

```
<ListBox  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Style1}"
```

And the item `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">             
    <Style.Triggers>                    
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property = "Effect"  >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="10" Direction="0" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="5" Color="Black"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
```

Simplified `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateSimple" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Example is simplified.

I also tried adding to the `DataTemplate`:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="GreenYellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
```

and assigning the shadow to it, but it would react only if `TextBlock`s are empty. Other ideas are appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As you can see it is not really a shadow but a blurry text.  If it was a shadow, it would change much on changing shadow length:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post, [How do I apply an effect to a Border but not to its contents in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807420/how-do-i-apply-an-effect-to-a-border-but-not-to-its-contents-in-wpf), which has some documentation on this "feature".

The easiest workaround in your case might be to give the Grid in your `DataTemplate` a background color:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateSimple" >
    <Grid Background="White" > ...
```

**EDIT:**

A more thorough approach would be to apply the `DropShadowEffect` to an element that lies beneath the text, but doesn't *contain* the text. For example, add a rectangle to your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateSimple" >
    <Grid Margin="2" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource RectStyle1}" 
                   Fill="Lime" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

..and instead of having the DropShadowEffect in `Style1`, put it in `RectStyle1`, but still triggered by IsMouseOver on the parent `ListBoxItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="RectStyle1" TargetType="Rectangle" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                       Path=IsMouseOver, 
                                       Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Effect" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="10" Direction="0" 
                                      Opacity="1" BlurRadius="5" 
                                      Color="Black" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That did not work. All child elements of ListBoxItem still have shadow.

Comment: Strange.. Could you post more of your xaml code (a complete page - not bits and pieces)?

Comment: I built a simple sln and it does seem to work but as much as I butcher my big project I can not find what is causing this... must be something global affecting this

Comment: I have also place in the code where I do the same effect in code and I still have text shadow but that part is not causing it on global level because I even after deletion it is happening. Any ideas which setting would cause this on global level?

Comment: I set .Net to 4.5 and I have just tried all of those in differnet combinations without success. If I would put border with shadow under the grid, would there be a way to trigger its visibility onMouseOver the grid (since it does not react when it is under the texblocks)

Comment: Yes, I believe there is. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: It works great! Thanks! I am again amazed how some things can be solved in wpf. Cheers!